# Navigation drawer icon checked change

Tags: java, android, navigation, sidebar, menuitem-selection

I have a fragment and an onTouch event to switch to another fragment

```
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int x = (int)event.getRawX();
                int y = (int)event.getRawY();

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_stars, fragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
                return false;
            }
```

But the icon in the sidebar doesn't change, it stays in the parent fragment
I tried to set checked in onCreateOptionsMenu but no work
Also I add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateView

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sidebar, menu);
        MenuItem item  = menu.findItem(R.id.sistemFragment);
        item.setChecked(true);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

sistemFragment is fragment I point to, but it doesn't change the cheched, it stays in the parent fragment

[image]

Comment: The menu parameter in `onCreateOptionsMenu` is of the options overflow menu (the three dots), it's different from the drawer menu which you can get from the [`navigationView.getMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView#getMenu())

Comment: Thanks, now I've read the navigation drawer documentation and it can be done simply with Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(R.id.sistemFragment) inside the event, that's all.
however now the Stars parent menu is disabled, the other menus work. I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it with NavigationUI, I'm not sure if it's the right way, but it works

```
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getRawX();
            int y = (int)event.getRawY();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) requireActivity()
                   .getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_sidebar);
                final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
                NavigationView nv = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                MenuItem item = nv.getMenu().getItem(0);
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).